# Is there a way of runing sequentially a project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Hi I want to execute a program I made in order to calculate the average result (not deterministic algorithm) and i need to run it A LOT of times. The program prints it's result in a different file everytime so it is not a problem. The problem is that i have to manually run the project thundreds of times, and i could automate it. I'm working ing windows, so i'd run a .bat file which executes the .exe generated into the debug folder, but when i execute that .exe, the program does not work properly, just does it when i push the "run" button. Is there a way of config the "run" button for use multiple times? Note that i need it won't be parallel but sequencially.

Comment: Why would you need to do that from the IDE's run button? Create a batch file with a loop, where each pass through the loop runs your app and the loop runs whatever number of times desired. Run the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you build a release and trigger that?
To my knowledge, there is no way to start a debug version outside of its debugger.